# Android Firestore loop returns empty list

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

i created two methods to get data from firestore. The first method is iterating over a list of attributes which are selected by the user. The other method is querying data depending on the selections of the user. After iterating over each item the new method needs to start. The problem is that my list is always empty, even though there is data available. Here are both methods:

```
 private void getStores(ArrayList<String> checkedItems) {
    newSeller = new ArrayList<>();
    sellers = new ArrayList<>();
    a = 0;

    for (int i =0; i<checkedItems.size(); i++){
        String checkedItem = checkedItems.get(i);
        int finalA = i;
        getStore(checkedItem);

    }
}

private void getStore(String checkedItem) {
    db.collection("Seller")
            .whereEqualTo("typ", checkedItem)
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                            SellerObject so = document.toObject(SellerObject.class);
                            so.setId(document.getId());
                            sellers.add(so);
                            Log.i(TAG, "onComplete: toa"+sellers.size());
                        }



                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: Your code looks fine, double check your Firestore database structure to make sure you are querying properly (also add the structure to your post if you need help)

Comment: now its working but the point is now, after my first loop the size of the list is only every seccond time the right one. I dont know why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are declaring the "sellers" array inside the first function but then trying to add to it from the second function. Move sellers out of the function so it can be reached.

Comment: but i have to clear the arrayList before i parse the data again. I also tried it with sellers.clear but this doesnt work out as well. If i remove this statement i have redundant values

Comment: i have now a different problem. Could you help me?